# Unable to timeout R's auto arima

Tags: r, machine-learning, timeout, time-series

I am trying to timeout the R's auto.arima at a give time threshold but it doesn't quit before completing the process. Following is my code snippet for auto.arima:

```
evalWithTimeout({
result_df <- data.frame()
meta_df <- data.frame()
train_data <- ts(data,frequency = 52)
model <- auto.arima(train_data, num.cores=1)
predictions <- forecast(model,h = 13)
},elapsed=5,timeout = 5)
```

The possible problem I can think of is auto.arima is invoking some C code underneath which could be causing the problem. Please let me know if there is some way to time it out.